# document.getElementById(..) is null

Tags: javascript

I recently started working in Javascript and I'm trying to create a basic Breakout game to practice. However, when I'm making the paddle and its movement Firebug says document.getElementById() is null. I already tried so many things to solve it but it isn't working. Can anyone give me a hand?

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Paddle</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = addListeners();
            function addListeners(){
            document.getElementById('paddle').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
            }
            function mouseDown(e){
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', cuadroMove, true);
            }

            function cuadroMove(e){
            var cuadro = document.getElementById('paddle');
            cuadro.style.position = 'absolute';
            cuadro.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
            cuadro.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="height:500px;width:500px;background-color:green;">
        <div id="paddle" style="width:100px; background-color:red">test</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your `onload` is using the return value of `addListeners`.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to assign an event handler for the load event, however:

```
window.onload = addListeners();
```

You are **calling** `addListeners` *immediately* and using the return value (`undefined`) as the event handler.

Remove the `()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. I tried what you said but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, it was my fault. Now it's already working. Thanks! And by the way, now I'm trying to write it inside one class near the other methods I used but then it stops working. Should I do something more about it or should it work just like that?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
window.onload = addListeners();
```

It expects the function body, not the function return value, so the right way is this:

```
window.onload = addListeners;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall use:

```
window.onload = addListeners;
```

or use jQuery library (http://www.jquery.com), shortcut for onload function looks like:

```
jQuery( function() {
 addListeners();
});
```

or:

```
jQuery(addListeners);
```

or:

```
window.addEventListener('load', addListeners, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the first one but it gives me the same error. I can't use Jquery for this so I checked the last one but when I write: window.addEventListener('load', mouseUp, false); It says mouseUp is not defined.

Comment: Ah, sorry: it could be:
`window.addEventListener('load', addListeners, false);`